# Print the page as it is in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I have tried using the https://github.com/gilf/ngPrint directive for print. I can able to print the page but the page design is completely collapsed while printing. Is there any possible way to print the page as it is?
Note: Am using Angular Material for the pages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the below piece of code:

```
function printPage() {
  var contentToPrint = document.getElementById('#myDiv').innerHTML;
  var windowPopup = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=500,height=500');
  windowPopup.document.open();
  windowPopup.document.write('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="" /></head><body onload="window.print()">' + contentToPrint + '</body></html>');
  windowPopup.document.close();
}
```

Comment: with this example maybe he'll got the same problem, must add the references of his css style, and the media, something like this:
 `<head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main.css"  type=\"text/css\" media=\"print\" /></head>`